# Dell Inspiron 530 - SSD Worth it?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, ssd, sata

I'm going to be upgrading my Dell Inspiron 530 (2.0 Ghz Intel Dual Core CPU, 3 GB RAM) to windows 7 soon, and rather than backup and reformat my existing drive, I'm planning on getting a 2nd drive to replace my current primary, and moving it to a secondary.  Thus, this seems like an excellent time to get a solid-state drive, if its going to be worth it.  As far as I can tell this machine has a SATA-I controller, and I'm unsure if I'll see a noticeable performance increase with an SSD without going to SATA-II.

So I have a three part question here given all that:

1. Will spending the money on a SSD be
   worth it if hook it into a SATA-I
   controller?
2. Is it reasonable to upgrade the
   controller on this machine to a
   SATA-II controller?
3. Given that this PC is kind of old to
   begin with, am I better off
   performance wise to just stick with
   a faster HDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. yes, Intel X-25 for performance or OCZ Vertex for value.
2. yes, altough not a necessity, the controller costs only $20.
3. no, the SSD will outperform even the fastest platter HDD.

Comment: do you mean Intel X-25?  as far as I can tell, IBM doesn't make SSD's

Answer (score 1):

I would also look into the [Seagate Momentus XT](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/laptops/laptop-hdd) if you don't want to drop a tonne of money on a SSD.

Comment: Didn't know they made hybrid drives. That's cool!

Comment: I was thinking of picking one up to put into my 2 year old Acer to bring some more life into it.

Answer (score -1):

Spending on an SSD would definitely benefit; provided you rely too much on read/write operations like video editing, photoshop etc. read/writing large chunks of data would be beneficial..